# How to have Mathematica pronounce/speak International Phonetic Alphabet?

Tags: sound

We know that `Speak` could read out English words and sentences such as

```
Speak["this is a sentence"]
```

Unfortunately, `Speak` only works for English. `Speak["これはぶんであります"]` will only yield silence.

In fact I'm learning Japanese, which also belongs to alphabetic languages (there are less than 100 letters). It's also interesting to make a simple program which could read Japanese words.

The pronunciation of Japanese letters could be imitated by using the International Phonetic Alphabet, so the problem has been converted to that of `Speak`ing  International Phonetic Alphabet by Mathematica.

Considering that the IPA (International Phonetic Alphabet) is nearly a set of complete bases for any language (maybe even the language of cats or birds), I'm looking for methods to pronounce IPA by Mathematica.

Part of vowel could be pronounced by code like

```
Speak["yi"]
Speak["ou"]
Speak["u"]
Speak["i"]
```

It's hard to find a complete string sets for all International Phonetic Alphabet.

How can this be done?

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible. Representing a rolled R will be difficult, for example, much less strongly tonal languages like Vietnamese or those with clicks and ejectives such as the Bantu languages. These have no analogs in standard English pronunciation, so no combination of letters can reproduce them. I think *Mathematica* is simply the wrong tool for the job, but you will find that the sounds of the IPA symbols are for the most part available as recordings on Wikipedia. By the way, there is a semi-standard notation for birdcalls and these are indeed not representable in IPA.

Comment: Good digital dictionaries (e.g. Barron's dictionaries) have recordings of the words that you can listen to, probably much better than what you can do yourself in Mathematica.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Can we have retroactive duplicates?

Comment: @m_goldberg IMO yes, if there is a reasonable answer.